# Why Does My Imported Gradle Java Project Not Display Errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am doing a small project for a job interview. To do it I had to import the basic files into my home instance of Eclipse through Gradle. I noticed about an hour into working on it, that for some reason no errors were displaying in Eclipse.

I could delete a semicolon or a closing bracket, and it does not throw an error.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I figure there is no way I've written multiple methods and classes, and not gotten some sort of error along the way.

Comment: You do have Gradle Integration installed, right? Just checking.

Comment: Yes, I had to install it to get the project loaded.

Comment: Try to re-import it and check for any errors during the import.